# How do I defeat the Scavenger Base boss?

Tags: star-trek-voyager-elite-force

I am on mission four - on the Scavenger Base, near the end of the mission I have come up against this guy who has a rapid fire weapon that *really* hurts, and whenever I shoot him he shields himself preventing him from taking any damage from me;

[image]

What is the best approach to defeat this guy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly this turns out to be little more than shooting the guy while he's not shielded. Once he dies he gives you a Tetryon Pulse Disruptor - the same weapon he was using.

[image]

Killing the boss simply involves shooting him until he shields, and then taking cover (using a combination of crouch and line of sight) while he's shooting. He can break certain cover by destroying it so be prepared to move if you hide behind the boxes littering the room.